# Adding Domains to AWS Cloudfront Distribution Via API

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I have a software application where I want to allow the client to whitelabel the application so they can re-sell it. To do this they would choose a custom domain (or subdomain) from their website to run my application on.

I'm running this application on AWS with CloudFront and AWS certificate Manager to manage the SSL. I'm able to add the "Alternate Domain Names" to the CloudFront distribution manually, but I'd love to do it via and API if possible so there is no "manual" updates. Is this possible?

In addition, and maybe more importantly, I need to figure out a scalable way to copy my SSL certificates so all existing domains remain certified, but I can simply "Add" one more... ideally via an API but I understand this MAY be a manual job.

The net of it is, I need to be able to programmatically add domains to my cloudfront distribution. If I have to hand-tool everything I fear it's an opportunity for a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the aws cli using this command: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html.

Something like this:

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution \
  --id EMLARXS9EXAMPLE \
  --distribution-config file://dist-config-disable.json
```

Where the contents of `dist-config-disable.json` include the new aliases (domain names) like so (abbreviated this file for brevity):

```
{
  ...
  "Aliases": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": ["example.com", "example2.com"]
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is so good! Thanks. So would that "dist-config-disable.json" be a FULL config of the entire distribution or do I dynamically create the file on-the-fly with just the Alternate Domains and then reference it in an API call?  Maybe something like export -> modify -> import: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/export-certificate.html

Am I crazy?

Comment: Honestly I would use infrastructure as code tools (probably terraform) to solve this problem, rather than writing a bespoke app/script

Comment: Also, if my answer was helpful, can you please accept it and upvote it?  Thanks! @MarkSinapi

Comment: Hey thanks! I can't yet because my reputation isn't high enough. Sorry.